# Wordpress Metabox Input - Add "Add Row" Button to Text Input

Tags: php, jquery, html, wordpress, input

I want to add an "Add Row" Button to my Metabox.
In this Metabox the user can write down keywords, that later will be displayed.
Because I don't know how many keywords the user will write down, I want the "Add Row" Button to add dynamically a new input row.

Here is a picture of what I want:
[image]

As you can see, I have 3 rows with text-input. When I click the "Add Row" Button, another Row with exactly the same text-inputs should be displayed.

I don't know how to realise that, but I know that it is possible.
Maybe some of you already did something like that and can help me find the solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Is it really necessary to write your own code? There`s an easier alternative....

Comment: Not necessarily. If you have an easier alternative, then I am interested in it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using a cmb2 as a plugin or framework? It has a built-in feature you need called 'repeatable fields'... [link](https://cmb2.io/docs/field-types). It won`t give you flexibility at first sight (as you wont be able to code any field inside wordpress metabox before learning some principles of this framework), but as for such a simple thing as repeatable fields it is dead simple:

```
$cmb->add_field( array(
    'name'    => 'Test Text', //field name
    'desc'    => 'field description (optional)', //field desc
    'default' => 'standard value (optional)', //self-explanatory, can be even a meta value
    'id'      => 'wiki_test_text', //field id - you can access it later via get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wiki_test_text', true)
    'type'    => 'text', //many pre-built types + external field types
    'repeatable' => true // here`s the magic - https://i.imgur.com/WSiYLrP.png (i speak mostly russian, but i think that the screenshot can be read even if you don`t understand russian...)
) );
```

This one has saved me tons of time!

Comment: Seems legit. I will give it a try. If it worked for me, you will get an upvote :)